# small image over large image hover css

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I know that this question has been asked before, but I've tried the other options and it hasn't worked correctly.

What I want to do is put a `.png` image over the placeholders without the `placeholder` being switched or removed to show the `.png`, I'm not entirely certain I even have my HTML set up correctly for that type of effect.

```
<ul class="portfolio-images">
    <li class="box-one"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x330"></li></a>
    <li class="box-two"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x330"></li></a>
    <li class="box-three"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x330"></li></a>
</ul>
```

Comment: May I ask for specifics? Do you add the new images after the page is loaded via Javascript or something?

Comment: I was trying to put my .png in via css , like how you would do a hover with a sprite. I did consider putting it in via java but I was having trouble finding anything that gave me an idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to add the png file to hide your placeholder image then this method will do the job. By adding an `:before` pseudo-element to the `a` inside the portfolio list.

http://liveweave.com/lx2OAr

The method is quite simple. The `:before` element will wrapped the entire content with 100% of `width` and `height`. And the `transition` will add some fade in and fade out effect to the element.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I wasn't trying to hide the placeholder simply have the .png over top and still be able to see the placeholder behind.

Comment: I guess I will have to ask for your full codes. Since you only gave me a list of placeholder images, that's the best I can help you. Or perhaps you can give any example from other website? Will try my best to help.

Comment: were you wanting full html, and css or just the code pertaining to the area I want to edit?

Comment: What do you mean actually with the ".png over top"? Are you trying to add a transparent png file to avoid your image from being stolen? Let me know. Thanks!

Comment: okay, it's similar to how when you hover over an image and a plus sign or magnifying glass symbol appear, but you can still see the image behind it. similar to what they do with a magnifying class symbol like this where you can still see the image behind it. http://webdesignandsuch.com/posts/jquery-image-rollover/ just with a png image.

Comment: Hey @sandalkoyak worked perfectly thanks so much for your help it turned out awesome!